# Adding features dynamically to an ArcGIS Javascript FeatureLayer with applyEdits()

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

When attempting to add features to a featureLayer with applyEdits, the features do not get added to the layer.

```
    var featureCollection = JSON.parse(mapdata);
    var features = JSON.parse(mapdata).featureSet.features;
    featureCollection.featureSet.features = [];
    var pointFeatures = [];
    var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(featureCollection, {
       id: 'HourlyDataLayer'
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
       if (features[i].attributes[selectedField] > maxValue) {
          maxValue = features[i].attributes[selectedField];
       }
       if (features[i].attributes[selectedField] < minValue) {
          minValue = features[i].attributes[selectedField];
       }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
       var feature = features[i];
       var size = (feature.attributes[selectedField] - minValue) * ((150 - 5) / (maxValue - minValue)) + 5
       var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, size,
           new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
           new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0]), 1), new dojo.Color([0, 255, 0, 0.25]));
       var attr = feature.attributes;
       var latlong = LatLonToWebMercator(feature.geometry.x, feature.geometry.y);
       var geometry = new esri.geometry.Point(latlong[0], latlong[1], spatialReference);
       var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry, symbol);
       graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
       graphic.setAttributes(attr);
       pointFeatures.push(graphic);
   }

   featureLayer.setEditable(true);
   featureLayer.applyEdits(pointFeatures, null, null);

   map.addLayers([featureLayer]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was really easy, but not at all intuitive to me, and I didn't see anything in documentation to suggest it, but you have to add the FeatureLayer to the map before you can apply edits:

```
    var featureCollection = JSON.parse(mapdata);
    var features = JSON.parse(mapdata).featureSet.features;
    featureCollection.featureSet.features = [];
    var pointFeatures = [];
    var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(featureCollection, {
       id: 'HourlyDataLayer'
    });

    map.addLayers([featureLayer]);

    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {....
    featureLayer.applyEdits(pointFeatures, null, null);
```

Comment: This seems to be broken at API v3.23. Works at 3.22. Is the API work on github or someplace where it's easy to file a bug report? Every time I try and find where to file I bug report I get worn out searching. :)